# Django 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: django, django-templates

In Django I want to use a simple template tag to truncate data.

This is what I have so far:

```
@register.filter(name='truncate_simple')
def truncate_char_to_space(value, arg):
    """
    Truncates a string after a given length.
    """
    data = str(value)
    if len(value) < arg:
        return data

    if data.find(' ', arg, arg+5) == -1:
        return data[:arg] + '...'
    else:
        return data[:arg] + data[arg:data.find(' ', arg)] + '...'
```

But when I use it I get the following error:

```
{{ item.content|truncate_simple:5  }}
```

**Error:**

'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 84: ordinal not in range(128)

Error is on line starting `data = str(value)`

Why?

Comment: did you try adding  "from __future__ import unicode_literals" to th top of python file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try to use unicode() to convert value (instead of str()):

```
data = unicode(value)
```

Comment: perfect, but could you explain.

Comment: Please don't randomly suggest adding a coding declaration. The question has nothing to do with that - it is for defining the encoding of character literals in the source file.

Comment: @DanielRoseman is right about coding declaration. To decoding character unicode(value) is sufficient.

Answer (score 29):

If you're using django and python 2.7 this fixes it for me:

```
from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Utente(models.Model):
```

see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.encoding.python_2_unicode_compatible

Comment: That is a best answer! Thanks!!! But you forgot *from django.utils.encoding import python_2_unicode_compatible*

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problems.

Answer (score 6):

@max4ever 's answer works for me. 
also sometimes you should put this line in the head of python files:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

it can be helpful when solving unicode encoding issues like this one.

Answer (score 4):

## in settings.py add this

```
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('UTF8')
```

Comment: This is actually bad idea, as it might break libraries that are using different encoding.