# Catching UnicodeEncodeError in Django render in a meaningful way

Tags: python, django, error-handling

I have a python script which is used to create static html files using Djnago templates. it looks like follows:

```
....
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.conf import settings
settings.configure()
template = """
   <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
             ..........................
             ..........................
   </html>
   """

t = Template(template)
c = Context({"field1":field1_from_program,
             "field2": some_dictionary,
              ......
              ......
              "field1000": some_other_list
            })

    f1=open(args.name+'.html', 'w+')
    try:
        f1.write(t.render(c).encode('utf-8'))
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        f1.write(t.render(c).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
    f1.close()
```

In some occasions, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 733, in <module>
    main()
  File "script.py", line 723, in main
    f1.write(t.render(c).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 209, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 201, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render
    bit = self.render_node(node, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 917, in render_node
    return node.render(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 957, in render
    output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 647, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 787, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/template/base.py", line 847, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I found some fields in the `content` were causing this error, so I added `.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')` to the variable which was causing this error. However, it is not obvious from the error log. There are many more such values, and the error message is not showing a verbose output on which field is causing this error. In other words, if `"field100":value_for_field100,`, I would want to know that it is the problem with `value_for_field100` may be using a try catch block.

In that sense, please note that my question is different than other SO questions such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974412/django-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte). Hence, I genuinely believe this is not a duplicate question.

Any tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: The result returned by t.render(c) is unicode, how about f1.write(t.render(c).encode('utf-8')) ?

Comment: @MujGabriel Well, that might fix the problem, but I want to know which field is causing the problem instead. Thanks anyways.

Comment: If you want to debug this you can try iterating over the dictionary (from Context) and apply str function on the value (do this inside a try/except and print the key and value) before doing any rendering.